# Unable to login into wp-admin

Tags: wordpress

I have created the blog for my website using WordPress. Earlier i was able to login to the WP-admin but currently i am not able to this and I am not getting any errors whether i am entering the correct username/password or in correct it always redirecting me to WP-login.php

I have not changed any WordPress files or anything database related. i don't understand how it was working before and not now.

please suggest something that could be the problem and a fix to try.

I have tried a couple of fixes but nothing has worked yet.

This is how my config connects to the database.

```
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'blog');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'test');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'test@12345');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

Comment: please refer http://codex.wordpress.org/Login_Trouble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First open your blog
then 
Go to the wp-config.php

- That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */
  After this line write
  define('RELOCATE',true);

then you will be able to login into the blog after that you change the blog url may be you have missed http:// or www or some problem in url the save it then again go the wp-config.php

and comment the line
define('RELOCATE',true);

That' all you have done

Answer (score -1):

You can access your database through phpmyadmin?
Then go to wp_users table and clear your passwort nearby your username.
Go to http://www.miraclesalad.com/webtools/md5.php type in your password and copy the resulting MD5 hash back in the field which you cleared.
Usually after this the password you inserted, is working in wp-login.

If you got the "cannot connect to database errror" problems can occur if your selected database "blog" maybe have different privileges.
Go to phpmyadmin and check your user privileges for "blog" or try to type in the wp-config for the default user root with no password.
DB_USER: "root"
DB_PASSWORD: ""

Comment: Now i am getting this error 
Fatal error: Internal zval's can't be arrays, objects or resources in Unknown on line 0